Export to CSV function not exporting Unicode characters correctly
I am exporting data from a collection into a CSV file in MongoDB Compass. Some data in the collection is Unicode and it shows up fine in Compass itself. However, when I export it to CSV file the data is not properly converted, the Unicode data shows up as these weird characters. What can be done to export it correctly?
I thought I could change the type of CSV to UTF-8 but Compass doesn't have this option.
